# iOS Objective-C UIButton action not working correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, uibutton, action

I am making a simple application for iphone (for learning and education purposes). Inside the .XIB file there is a button used to clear all text fields on the screen. I create a "clear:" method for the button. assign the method to "Touch Up Inside", but when I run the app in iOS Simulator the button acts like the "clear:" method has been assigned to "Touch Up Outside". I click the button nothing happens, I click and hold the button then drag my mouse pointer outside of the button and let go and all text fields clear. Can anyone help me make it so "Touch Up Inside" works properly? (If I am completely mistaken, and sound like a noob just tell me, I am a beginner)

Comment: Is this question about Mac or iOS development?

Comment: @Rickay iOS, I will go and edit the post now for more clarification, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Can you try this on an iPhone?

Comment: @Rayfleck I currently dont have a developers subscription, so I cannot.

Comment: Simulators are not perfect, perhaps it's a bug.  Can you try a sim for a different iOS version, such as 4.2 or 4.1?

Comment: @Rayfleck How would you go about doing that? all i have is iphone 5.0, ipad 5.0 and ios device and xcode wont let me use ios device.

Comment: Then you can't.  By the way, have you tried the basic stuff, like: 1) clean the project, 2) In the sim, run "reset Content and Settings..." from the main menu, and 3) close and re-open XCode?

Comment: @Rayfleck I have done the last 2, no luck, but how would you do the first one?

Comment: Project/Clean  or Shift-Command-K

Comment: @Rayfleck Ok I was playing around with my app and now not only can you accomplish the task by dragging out but also if you hold it there for longer the 2 seconds then let go of the button it will execute. weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you have it hooked up correctly to TouchUpInside?  Try deleting that Send Event association, and redoing it.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes it looks just like that except for the Referencing Outlet. Do I need the referencing outlet? Currently I only have the touch up inside connection.

Comment: You only need the referencing outlet if you want to explicity make use of this button inside of your code (such as to programmatically disable it).